# What should I say about this poorly defined question?

Tags: soft-question, binary-operations

*If this is a duplicate in any way, I'm sorry; I couldn't find anything.*

### The Details:

I saw this question on Facebook just now:

> If
>
> - $2+3=10,$
> - $7+2=63,$
> - $6+5=66,$
>
> then $11+12=?$

The intended answer, I suppose, is $253$; the pattern you're supposed to infer is $a+b=a(a+b)$.

### The Question:

> If you're being pedantic, isn't this problem ill-defined? Can't you get any answer? What should I say about it to educate those answering the question?

### Thoughts:

It should be some other binary operation, like $+'$, say, instead of $+$, but the above is how the question is posed. If $2+3=10$, anything follows.

Three values of a binary operation (on, say, $\Bbb N$) isn't enough to pin down other values.

Comment: Tell the problem-solvers: this is a waste of your time. It does nothing useful other than to serve as a part of a Mensa entrance test.

Comment: "What should I say about it to educate those answering the question?" I don't understand why you'd bother saying anything at all to a question on Facebook. Live and let live...

Comment: Whether you add the soft-question tag or not, this is not a mathematics question.  Anything from Facebook is almost surely bogus, anyway, aimed at folks who get invested in them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at this question in a couple of ways.

1. The logical statement 'A implies B' is always true if A is false, so since $2+3$ is not $10$, the answer can be anything.
2. If you are talking about patterns, and take the plus symbol to be some kind of correspondence instead, then the given answer is just one possibility: there is no guarantee that the pattern is indeed $a(a+b)$. Moreover, the plus symbol really shouldn't be used here, because it normally represents normal addition.

I definitely won't set this kind of question in any respectable math exam, though the ability to see patterns is commonly tested in some IQ exam.

Comment: No this is not a typical (genuine) IQ test question, @PhilipRoe.  Only a "fake IQ test question".

Comment: You say '$2 + 3 \neq 10$' and that the $+$ symbol is normally used for normal addition, but this is wrong. First of all the $+$ is used to represent the operation of (usually an abelian) group, and in this group $2+3=10$ could be a true statement. Take for example the group $(\{0\},+)$ with $0 + 0 =:0$. Here we have $x + y = z$ for any $x$,$y$,$z$.

Comment: @getrektm8: Note however that in the probable intended answer, the + operation does not commute, i.e. we don't have an abelian group here.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis how do we know that it does not commute? you are already assuming that the $+$ in the question represents $a+b=a(a \times b)$, where $\times$ denotes the natural addition on $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @getrektm8 Yes, I'm assuming $a(a+b)$ is their intended answer. I'm just saying that even though + is used generally in maths to stand for the operation in an abelian group, their intended answer here is not an abelian group so their use of + is still misleading. Come to think of it, it probably isn't a group at all as I don't think there are always inverses of this operation.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis oh now i get what you mean. And i just checked the group axioms, it actually does not meet any requirements whatsoever.

Comment: 1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221, 312211, 13112221 :)