# Interpolation polynomials for $n$-tuples.

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

*I apologise if this is a duplicate in any way or is off topic.*

Given a (finite) set $S$ of $n$-tuples of real numbers, is there an [interpolation polynomial](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Interpolation+polynomial&wal=header) that goes through each $s\in S$?

### Motivation.

A common type of problem found on social media is to infer a pattern from a list of triples, usually in the form of a few evaluations of a binary operation, then apply that pattern to a couple. For instance,

> If
>
> - $2+3=10,$
> - $7+2=63,$
> - $6+5=66,$
>
> then what is $11+12$?

The intended answer is presumably  $253$; the pattern you're supposed to infer is "$a+b=a(a+b)$".

It is my suspicion that the answer [could be *anything*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2403586/what-should-i-say-about-this-poorly-defined-question) with enough imagination or, indeed, something akin to an interpolation polynomial.

Comment: You're intending that the last entry of the tuple is the output of a polynomial in the preceding $n - 1$ entries?

Comment: Yes, @Mr.Chip. ${}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $s = (s_1, \dots, s_{n-1}, s_n) \in S$, define the following polynomial:
$$f_s = (x_1 - s_1)^2 + \dots + (x_{n-1} - s_{n-1})^2.$$
Then let 
$$f = \sum_{s \in S} s_n \prod_{s' \ne s}  \frac{f_{s'}}{f_{s'}(s_1, \dots, s_{n-1})}.$$
You'll now have $f(s_1, \dots, s_{n-1}) = s_n$. The idea is simply to generalise the factors $x - s$ in usual Lagrange interpolation to these functions $f_s$, which are chosen to be zero precisely at the point $s$.